# How to read this data from .dat file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, import, format, fopen, fixed-width

I would like to read the following data from .dat file which are delimited by fixed width (14,34,54,74). As unique string can be used "nblock" but after it, 1 line should be skipped because this -> (1i9,3e20.9e3) is not needed. End of reading is marked with "-1":

```
nblock, 3,,1815
(1i9,3e20.9e3)
       1   1.38E-14     1.45E+02     5.49E-01
       2   0.00E+00     8.94E-05     4.19E-13
... 
    1649   6.87E-01     1.25E+02     4.99E-01
-1
```

I would like to ask you for help.

```
filename = 'D5_A.dat';
fid = fopen(filename,'r');
S = textscan(fid, '%14f %21f %21f %21f');
fclose(fid)
```

Best regards

Michal

Comment: Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: A = regexp(fileread('D5_A.dat'),'\n','split'); whichline = find(contains(A,'nblock')) I am able to 'nblock' string but also I would like to find string '-1' which is only one in line, but I don't know how to specify it. I would like to ask you for help.